# Why is my hash key slow?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Since a few months, I've noticed that my hash key (#) was really slow. I'm using an AZERTY keyboard since I'm from France, and I'm using Windows 10 latest stable build. Filter keys and all accessibility options are disabled.

I have absolutely no idea about what is causing this, I'm using a Logitech G105 Refresh and it's always been working fine.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it slow in Notepad? Or just sites where the pound key is frequently used to do something like link to relevant posts?

Comment: @AthomSfere It was slow basically everywhere. I noticed it when I was using Zanata (a translation website), because I had to type quite a few of them (Markdown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, actually the issue seems to be caused by ASUS GPU Tweak.

It considers that the key combo Alt gr. + #  is the same as Ctrl + Alt + 3, which is true.

So you have two options to fix this issue:

1) You disable the hotkeys in GPU Tweak, but that will cause the key to not be able to be used multiple times in a row.

or

2) You stop using GPU Tweak and your keyboard goes back to normal.